# PHP preg_split remove last occurence if it is the end of the string

Tags: php, preg-split

I have a string that is build like this:

```
$value = "0::1\n1::4\n2::5\n";
```

Which I split with a preg_split:

```
$result = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $value);
```

This gives me an array, the problem is that the last "\n"is not removed. Is there a flag with preg_split to remove this as well?

array:

```
array(
  0 = "0::1",
  1 = "1::4",
  2 = "2::5\n"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such flag. Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to remove it:

```
$result = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m', $value);
$result = array_map('trim', $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solution could be:

```
var_dump(array_filter(explode("\n", $value)));
```

**Output**:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "0::1"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1::4"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "2::5"
}
```